# "query has no destination for result data" error even after having return in the function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Below is my function, even after having a `RETURN` statement, but a

> query has no destination for result data

error is thrown. Am I missing something?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(ulds character varying)
 RETURNS boolean AS
 $BODY$
 DECLARE
 val_result boolean;
 BEGIN
           select * from regexp_split_to_array('BLK&AAK&AKE', '&');
           SET val_result = false;

 RETURN val_result;       
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION test(character varying)
```

Comment: you run query `select * from regexp_split_to_array('BLK&AAK&AKE', '&');` then it never used?

Comment: @RyanNghiem Does that matter ?

Comment: Either remove the unused query or put a `PERFORM ` in front of it. But removing seems the better option as there seems little to no point in executing a query when the result isn't used at all.

Comment: That query doesn't belong there. get rid of it.

Comment: @RyanNghiem yess, I got it. Thanks (y)

Comment: @KaushikNayak, yes I was just testing something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one issues:

1. Result of unbind queries is not result of function in Postgres. You need to use `INTO clause`.
2. `regexp_split_to_array` is scalar function, there is not any reason to call this function from `SELECT` statement. Use `SELECT` only when you take result of table function, or when you need to read data from relations.
3. assign statement in plpgsql is based on `:=` symbol. The command `SET` is used for something different.
4. the type `text` is proffered against `varchar` for function's parameters.

So your code can looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(ulds text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
  result boolean;
  target text[];
BEGIN
  -- suboptimal, don't do this!!!
  SELECT regexp_split_to_array('BLK&AAK&AKE', '&') INTO target;

  -- preferred
  target := regexp_split_to_array('BLK&AAK&AKE', '&');

  result := true;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: sure, I did comment there, but I will wrote other line to example.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so clearly. I thought `SET` would do the job. `SET` is used at all in postgres ?

Comment: `SET` is used for setting configuration per session